# When does onException get triggered in WebDriverEventListener?

Tags: java, events, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using a custom WebDriverEventListener in my Selenium tests for logging and screenshot purposes. It works fine:

When for example an element is not found in the browser window an exception is thrown by the webdriver and the onException() method is properly triggerd

```
@Override
public void onException(Throwable throwable, WebDriver driver) {
    // do stuff
}
```

When I throw an Exception myself like this: `throw new WebDriverException("my message");` the event is not triggered.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand that because the listener is only registered to the WebDriver itelf it won't handle exceptions outsite the WebDriver.

In the abstract test case I did the following as part of a suggestion by [Andrian Durlestean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826186/andrian-durlestean).

```
eventListener = new CustomWebDriverEventListener();
driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver).register(eventListener);

@Rule
public TestWatcher  watchman = new TestWatcher() {

    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        RuntimeException exception = (RuntimeException) e;
        eventListener.onException(e, getDriver());
        if (exception instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw exception;
        }   
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some action when test failed or some exception, you can add to your test a rule(add in class where is @Before setUp()):

```
@Rule
public TestRule testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void succeeded(Description test){
        for (LogEntry log : driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.DRIVER).getAll()) {
            System.out.println("Level:" + log.getLevel().getName());
            System.out.println("Message:" + log.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Time:" + log.getTimestamp());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        }
        System.out.println();

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable t, Description test) {

        String testName = test.getClassName();
        String subTestName = test.getMethodName();
        String screenShotName = String.format("%s\\%s", testName, screenShotName);
        if (driver instanceof TakesScreenshot) {
          File tempFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
          try {
              System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>LOGS: " + yourDirForImages + "\\" + screenShotName + ".png");
              FileUtils.copyFile(tempFile, new File(String.format("%s.png", screenShotName)));
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
```

}

Listener can be used for doing some code when its trigger some action, beforeCLick if there is header, logo, or footer.

```
public class ListenerMethodsImplementation extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener {

    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver myTestDriver) {
    assertTrue("No Logo!", myTestDriver.findElements(By.id("logo")) == 1);
}
```

How to use it:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        EventFiringWebDriver myTestDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        ListenerMethodsImplementation myListener = new ListenerMethodsImplementation();
        myTestDriver.register(myListener);
        driver = myTestDriver;
    }
```

How to get driver from listener: `((EventFiringWebDriver) driver).getWrappedDriver()`

PS it's only a little portion from my code but i think this will help you.

Comment: thanks, I am already using some of the events from WebDriverEventListener like you are showing.
But I think I understand my problem: the listener is registered to the WebDriver. Thereby when an exception occurs outside the WebDriver no event will be triggered

Comment: alright, I used a testWatcher as you suggested. Inside the `failed(Throwable e, Description description)` method I call `myEventListener.onException(e, driver);`

Comment: Test watcher must be in class where is setUp() @Before using your test

Comment: yes, I have put it in my Abstract Test Case. Where @ Before and @ After are also implemented. thanks